# Topological space with special property

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading notes on algebraic topology and in a proof the following statement is being made taken out of context: "just take any topological space $X$ such that $H_0(X) \cong H_1(X) \cong H_2(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$"

I can't think of a topological space such that this holds, and looking back in the notes no such example is given. Can anyone provide such an example?

Answer (score 1):

How about $S^1\vee S^2$? In general, if you are trying to construct spaces with arbitrary homology groups, wedge sums are the key.

A wedge sum is the same as a one-point union which is the quotient of the disjoint union of a collection of based topological spaces $\{(X_i,x_i)\}$ by the equivalence relation identifying each basepoint in each space to the same point.

So in my example, the resulting space looks like a circle and a sphere tangent at one point.

Comment: My notes does not include anything about wedge sums, do you have a complete answer? How can I see that your space works?

Comment: I would insist that you take out a pen and paper and compute the homology groups of $S^1\vee S^2$. It's a good exercise

Comment: Of course I would do that, however my book does not include anything on wedge sums. I was just asking you to enligheten me on this. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Is it the definition of wedge sum that you are missing? Given two spaces $X,Y$ (with base points $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ implicitly specified), their wedge sum $X \vee Y$ is the quotient space of the disjoint union $X \coprod Y$ where $x$ and $y$ are identified to a single point. If that's not enough to help you calculate the homology of $S^1 \vee S^2$, then you'll also need to learn about things like Mayer-Vietoris sequences and/or homology of CW complexes.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: You can also take $S^1\times S^2$, which is $S^1\wedge S^2$ with a 3-cell attached.

Comment: @Tyrone i have works out the example rocket man gave, you are welcome to post an answer with respect to your comment.

Comment: Oops. My comment should read $S^1\times S^2$ is $S^1\vee S^2$ with a 3-cell attached. The point was that it was perhaps a simpler example for you of a space $X$ with the required properties. The reason is, however, because $S^1\vee S^2\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^2$ induces isomorphisms on $H_*$ for $*=0,1,2$, so it doesn't add anything new to Rocket Man's more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. As the book never even mentioned wedge sums, do you have any other examples? Just curious although this was a good example.